# Find a number $\alpha > 1$ such that the following holds

Tags: calculus

> We want to find a real number $\alpha > 1$ such that
>
> $$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ dx }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} = 1
>  $$

#### What I got so far

First, I used Integration by parts to obtain

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ dx }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} = \underbrace{\frac{x}{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} \bigg|_0^{\infty}}_{=0} + \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2 x^{\alpha} }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha+1}} dx $$

Now, notice

$$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2 (x^{\alpha}  +1 -1)}{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha+1}} dx = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2  }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} dx - \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2  }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha+1}} dx  $$

Therefore, for our original integral to be $1$, we must have

$$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2  }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} dx =1+ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2  }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha+1}} dx $$

But, notice

$$ 1 = - \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} dx }{(1+ x^{\alpha} )^{\alpha}} $$

Thus, the above expression is equivalent to

$$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^2+\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}  {(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha^2  }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha+1}} dx $$

Therefore,

$$ (1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}(\alpha^2 + \alpha x^{\alpha-1} ) = \alpha^2 $$

holds for all $x>0$. In particular, if $x=1$, we have

$$ 2(\alpha^2 + \alpha) = \alpha^2 $$

but this equation has no solution  $\alpha>1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you didn't do any algebra mistakes, it means that the equation $ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ dx }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} = 1
 $ can not be satisfied with the given condition, i.e the statement is false because in your 3th step, you assumed the the original equation is equal to 1, and you reach something that can not be satisfied within the given premises, which means the equation is not equal to 1.

Comment: @leth The equation must have a solution, since the integral is a continuous function of $a$ and it goes to $\infty$ for $a \searrow 1$ and to $0$ for $a \to \infty$.

Comment: You can't deduce from $\int f(x)dx=\int g(x)dx$ that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Dominik good point, then you have a algebraic mistake, which is pointed out by TonyK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving $\int_0^\infty\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^n)^n}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946919/solving-int-0-infty-dfracdx1xnn-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try some numbers in Wolframalpha and came up with the conjecture (I'm very sure is true).
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)^\alpha} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-\frac{1}{\alpha})\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(\alpha)}.
\end{align}
If you set 
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-\frac{1}{\alpha})\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=1
\end{align}
we see that there is a solution on the interval $(1, 2)$. Solving for $\alpha$ yields
\begin{align}
\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.
\end{align}

Edit: Observe
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)^\alpha} =&\ \alpha \int^\infty_0 \frac{\alpha x^\alpha}{(1+x^\alpha)^{\alpha+1}}\ dx
 =\ \alpha \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{1/\alpha}}{(1+t)^{1+\alpha}}\ dt\\
 =&\ \alpha B(1+1/\alpha, \alpha-1/\alpha) =\ \alpha\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-\frac{1}{\alpha})\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\\
=&\ \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-\frac{1}{\alpha})\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})}{\Gamma(\alpha)}.
\end{align}

Comment: It is true. See equation $(22)$ in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: @MarcoCantarini I was just looking up how to turn the expression into the beta function.

Comment: Now relate it to the n'th Fibonacci number

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is the solution.

Edit because of the downvote:

$\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)^\alpha}=\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x^\frac{1}{\alpha-1})^\alpha}=x(x^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}+1)^{1-\alpha}=x(x^\alpha+1)^{1-\alpha}$

So $\int^\infty_0\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)^\alpha}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x(x^\alpha+1)^{1-\alpha}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x}{(x^\alpha+1)^\frac{1}{\alpha}}=1$

Edit: $\alpha=\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$ as $\alpha$ is the golden ratio

Comment: I came to the same result by numerical heuristics, but do you have a proof ?

Comment: @Peter how did you do it numerically?

Comment: I used the solve-command in PARI/GP and noticed that the solution seems to be the inverse of the golden ratio.

Comment: I verified it and could approve it within an accuracy of about $10^{-500}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha = \phi\textrm{( the golden ratio )}, \textrm{ then }\alpha^2-\alpha -1=0,$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^\alpha\right)^\alpha} d x & \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}  \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\right)^\alpha} \frac{d x}{-x^2} \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha^2-2}}{\left(x^\alpha+1\right)^\alpha} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\left(x^\alpha+1\right)^\alpha} d \alpha \\
& =\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x^\alpha+1\right)}{\left(x^\alpha+1\right)^\alpha} \\
& =\frac{1}{\alpha}\left[\frac{\left(x^\alpha+1\right)^{\alpha+1}}{-\alpha+1}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)} {(-1)} \\
& =1
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your equation

$$ 1 = - \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} dx }{(1+ x^{\alpha} )^{\alpha}} $$
can't be correct. Note that the integral of a positive function is again positive. Instead,
$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{ \alpha x^{\alpha - 1} dx }{(1+ x^{\alpha} )^{\alpha}} = \left.\frac{(x^\alpha + 1)^{1 - \alpha}}{1 - \alpha} \right|_0^\infty = \frac{1}{\alpha - 1}$$
is correct.