# $ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ dx }{(1+x^{\alpha})^{\alpha}} = 1 $ where $\alpha$ is the golden ratio

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

If got this question from here: [Find a number $\alpha > 1$ such that the following holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970743/find-a-number-alpha-1-such-that-the-following-holds/1970803#1970803)

I was wondering if something with my answer is wrong, as it still has a downvote.

Let $\alpha$ be the golden ratio, so ‎especially $\alpha=\frac{1}{\alpha-1}$ holds.

$\int\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)^\alpha}=\int \dfrac{dx}{(1+x^\frac{1}{\alpha-1})^\alpha}=x(x^{\frac{1}{\alpha-1}}+1)^{1-\alpha}=x(x^\alpha+1)^{1-\alpha}$

So $\int^\infty_0\dfrac{dx}{(1+x^\alpha)^\alpha}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x(x^\alpha+1)^{1-\alpha}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x}{(x^\alpha+1)^\frac{1}{\alpha}}=1$

Comment: Maybe, the downvoter did not notice the edit.

Comment: Voting to close. This is just an answer to another question.

Comment: Why is it an answer to another question?

Comment: Well duh. It's an answer to the question in your link.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for downvoting... I'm leaving this site, ppl seem to be very rude and nobody answers my question for which I opend up an account here...